# Android 5.0 odd behaviour with background drawable

Tags: android, image, background, android-5.0-lollipop

I have notice some odd behaviour on Android 5.0 lollipop. When I have some view with background drawable like LinearView and android:background="@drawable/image". When my app crash (Unexpected error!) than (only sometimes) the background disappears and there is in background only black screen (as if this drawable has been deleted)

I also see some odd behaviour with 2 Images where they are blinking, and not appearing...

On Notification when it appears on top there is some odd red rectangle by few seconds and it is changed then to proper icon.

App has been working perfectly well on Android 4.4 but after installing Android 5.0 firmware it seems to have this odd behaviour.

I omit that there is problem with fonts/ colores of text labels and enforced uppercase letters

Is there somewhere what has changed/stopped working in typical controls and how it should be appropriately fixed?

Update!
After restarting my app it works correctly! But such behaviours could motivate potential users to rather uninstall app than restart their phone!

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same issue. At the beginning the app was crashing for OOM (OutOfMemory). Managing in a better way the memory the app wasn't crashing anymore but the same behavior (the background disappears and there is in background only black screen) could be reproduced through Settings > More > Application manager > MyApp > FORCE STOP. Opening the app was behaving strange again (background gone). Clearing Data (or restarting the device) and opening the app again was the only way to fix the problem till the next crash/force-stop.

In main activity there was basically something like this

```
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(1024*1024*5);
//...
```

and I changed it like this:

```
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
//...
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
int availMemInBytes = am.getMemoryClass() * 1024 * 1024;
mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(availMemInBytes/8 );
```

Previous code was assigning the "maxSize" without considering the effective available memory. The new code fix this.
I'm not sure if this issue was related to the new ART (Android OS till 4.4.2 use Dalvik, newest use ART) or some other API change, BTW with the code above I solved. 
I hope will be useful for some else.